# Regex replace more than one string in Vim

Tags: regex, vim

I have documents with groups of `<hr/>` tags:

```
<p>stuff</p>
<hr/>
<hr/>
<hr/>
<p>stuff</p>
```

Grateful for tip how to replace with a single instance of this tag in Vim.

Comment: And you didn't talk about any attempt.

Comment: Top marks for observation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this search-replace in `vim`:

```
:%s/<hr\/>\n\(<hr\/>\n\)\+/\1/
```

`<hr\/>\n\(<hr\/>\n\)\+` will find 2 or more lines containing `<hr/>` and we replace it using `\1` which is `<hr/>\n`.

Comment: Nice, thanks. Do parentheses replace square brackets in Vim?

Comment: Actually sorry I'm getting `E488: Trailing characters`

Comment: Re square brackets no it's just I was trying earlier to achieve this with `[<hr\/>]` but always get `Pattern not found`

Comment: That works ta. I just got `:%s/<hr\/>\(\n<hr\/>\)\+/<hr\/>/r` to work also. Super helpful thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can make `<hr/>\n` a group and search for multiples of it, replacing
with  a  single  one. Also  note  that  in  Vim  you can  use  different
delimiters, which  is specially helpful  if you're working  with slashes
for example. And  you don't need to close the  substitute command if you
don't have flags.

```
:%s#\(<hr/>\n\)\+#\1
```

With `\v` to  enable very magic, even more escaping  is avoided. However
the `<` and `>` will be treated  as special word boundaries. So you have
to escape them instead.

```
:%s#\v(\<hr/\>\n)+#\1
```

And of course, if the only duplicated lines in your file are those tags,
this is enough as well:

```
:%!uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

Also works:

```
:%s/\(<hr\/>\n\)\+/<hr\/>\r
```